# save array in controller laravel

Tags: laravel

**ErrorException
Array to string conversion**

```
    $presocio              = new Presocio;
    $presocio->prestamo_id = $request->prestamo_id;
    $presocio->ncuota      = $request->ncuota;
    $presocio->montopag    = $request->montopag;
    $presocio->fechapag    = $request->fechapag;
    $presocio->save();
```

In the end I managed to make it work like this, it works perfectly.
it can be done in different ways, example with **::create** **::insert**

```
    $prestamo           = new Prestamo;
    $prestamo->socio_id = $request->socio_id;
    $prestamo->monto    = $request->monto;
    $prestamo->cuotas   = $request->cuotas;
    $prestamo->alias    = $request->alias;
    $prestamo->save();

    $idprestamo = $prestamo->id;

    if (count($request->ncuota) > 0) {
        foreach ($request->ncuota as $item => $v) {
            $presocio = new Presocio;
            $presocio->fill(
                array(
                    'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
                    'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
                    'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
                    'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
                )
            );
            $presocio->save();
        }
    }
    toast('Pago Programados Registrado', 'success');
    return redirect('prestamo');
```

Comment: Which line in this code causes this error?

Comment: you want to save data in Database?

Comment: share your view code

Comment: send array from my view, and the error of: ErrorException Array to string conversion

Comment: they are all arrays, what do you want to do with these arrays?

Comment: @SergioNC You can save records using loop through. Try my answer.

Comment: @SergioNC I have updated my answer.

Comment: @michael-mano  update the code

Answer (score 1):

Update since we now have the form supplied. You are using form names such as `ncuota[]` instead of `ncuota` which makes it an array. Are you able to make more than 1 Preseocio? if this is the case you want to loop over the items in the controller.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->ncuota); $i++)
{
    Presocio::create([
        'prestamo_id' => $request->prestamo_id[$i],
        'ncuota' => $request->ncuota[$i],
        'montopag' => $request->montopag[$i],
        'fechapag' => $request->fechapag[$i],
    ]);
}
```

Otherwise just remove the `[]` off the end of the form names.

```
class Presocio
{
    ...
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'prestamo_id',
        'ncuota',
        'montopag',
        'fechapag',
    ];
    ...
}
```

`Presocio::create($request->all());`

Now, Thats not the issue. That is just a bit of house keeping.

Your issue is that one of your request fields is an Array. Which ever one it is you will need to convert it to a JSON object or find a better way of storing it.
If you dont care and want to keep it as an array, modify the database field to be a `jsonb` field.

Comment: the `create` method takes an array

Comment: That's what the request is. That is not the array im talking about converting. He is trying to store an array in a string field.

Comment: good now, but yes they have some input that is an array and is causing the error most likely

Comment: I have my html table and with jquery add rows, the inputs are "name []"
I execute dd ($ presocio); brings array of data sent.

Comment: @SergioNC Can you show which line of code error occurs?

Comment: @SergioNC can you update your question with your form.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This create method**

remove your all code and write only this code in your store method

```
$input = $request->all();
Presocio::create($input);
```

Comment: please select this answer if this answer is helpful THANK YOU@SergioNC

Comment: please write in cooment not as a answer.

Comment: explain how that is different than what they are doing and how this solves their problem

Comment: I have my html table and with jquery add rows, the inputs are "name []"
I execute dd ($ presocio); brings array of data sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($request->input('prestamo_id', 'ncuota', 'montopag', 'fechapag')); $i++) {

    $presocio              = new Presocio;
    $presocio->prestamo_id = $request->prestamo_id[$i];
    $presocio->ncuota      = $request->ncuota[$i];
    $presocio->montopag    = $request->montopag[$i];
    $presocio->fechapag    = $request->fechapag[$i];
    $presocio->save();
}
```

Comment: with jquery I add row, to have more fields. When sending, only the last row is saved by the controller

Comment: @SergioNC That is why everyone told you please put you Html and jquery code into your question.

Comment: @SergioNC If your code is too lengthy. don not worry. You should put your logic only. Like how you can add a row?

Comment: I generate several rows to fill, but when I make the shipment, just register the first row

Comment: @SergioNC I have tried the above code. It is working fine using loops. I don't know your shipment logic. You should try to `echo '<pre>';
            print_r($request->prestamo_id[$i]);` inside for loop. check all the entered value returns or not??